# How to install azure-cli on python docker image

Tags: python, azure, docker, azure-cli

I am trying to install `azure-cli` in a `python` docker container but I get the following error:

> [5/5] RUN pip3 install azure-cli:
> #9 1.754 Collecting azure-cli
> #9 1.956   Downloading azure_cli-2.43.0-py3-none-any.whl (4.3 MB)
> #9 7.885      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.3/4.3 MB 730.7 kB/s eta 0:00:00
> #9 8.070 Collecting six>=1.10.0
> #9 8.190   Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
> #9 8.227 Collecting azure-loganalytics~=0.1.0
> . . .
> #9 43.08 ERROR: Exception:
> . . .
> #9 43.08     raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
> #9 43.08   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/contextlib.py", line 130, in **exit**
> #9 43.08     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
> #9 43.08   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/response.py", line 449, in _error_catcher
> #9 43.08     raise SSLError(e)
> #9 43.08 pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: KRB5_S_TKT_NYV] unexpected eof while reading (_ssl.c:2570)
> #9 43.28 WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
> #9 43.28 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

---

executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip3 install azure-cli]: exit code: 2

And here's my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

RUN apk add --update git bash curl unzip make coreutils openssh shadow

ARG TERRAFORM_VERSION="1.3.6"
ARG svgUserId=
ENV AZURE_DEFAULT_REGION=germanywestcentral

RUN if ! id $svgUserId; then \
    adduser svg -D &&\
    usermod -u ${svgUserId} svg; \
  fi

RUN curl https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip > terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
  unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -d /bin && \
  rm -f terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip

RUN pip3 install azure-cli

ENTRYPOINT []
```

Can someone help me find the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to [install azure-cli in alpine](https://www.rokpoto.com/install-azure-cli-dockerfile-alpine/) image:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --update python3 py3-pip 
RUN apk add --no-cache --update --virtual=build gcc musl-dev python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev cargo make && pip3 install --no-cache-dir --prefer-binary azure-cli && apk del build
```

As you use Python alpine image, the first `RUN` command is redundant in your case.

Comment: here you create a virtual package named "build", so you must write "apk del build"

Answer (score 0):

I'm running image python:3.11-slim and got away with the lines below.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --prefer-binary azure-cli
RUN az config set auto-upgrade.enable=yes
```